# Google Compute Engine Stop Hostname From Resetting On Reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine

I know this question has been asked already but I can not find a solution that actually works! The main solution that I have found everywhere and tried is by setting a cron job for when the system reboots with :

```
@reboot hostname $(curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

This is after adding the metadata `hostname` key in the instance settings and it just doesn't work and the hostname keeps getting reset to the name of the instance (I need it as a FQD)

Does anyone have a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

At creation time, you can set a custom FQDN hostname for your VMs via the optional hostname property. This feature is currently in Beta. ex:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME --hostname custom.hostname.xyz
```

[More info the docs.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm)